# Using OpenXML to generate a spreadsheet and trying to get &[Page] of &[Pages] working in a custom footer

Tags: c#, openxml, epplus

This seems to be a simple issue of escaping a string but I cannot figure out the correct format and I cannot find documentation with examples of using fields in Excel footers.

The property in question is:

```
xlSheet.HeaderFooter.OddFooter.LeftAlignedText = "&[Page] of &[Pages]";
```

Here is a larger snippet of the code generating the worksheet for additional context:

```
 using (ExcelPackage pckExport = new ExcelPackage())
            {
                ExcelWorksheet xlSheet = pckExport.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(SystemEnum.GetEnumDescription(typeof(SystemEnum.Reports), SystemEnum.Reports.GroomingCalendarReport.GetHashCode()));
                try
                {
                    int miRow = 1;
                    string pageHeader = "Calendar Report";
                    xlSheet.Cells.Style.Font.Size = 9;
                    xlSheet.Cells.Style.Font.Name = "Times New Roman";
                    DateTime reportDate = Convert.ToDateTime(rptDate);
                    ////set the report header
                    xlSheet.HeaderFooter.OddHeader.CenteredText = "&\"Times New Roman,Bold\"&12" + "\n" + pageHeader + "\n" + " &11for&12 " + reportDate.Date.DayOfWeek.ToString() + " , " + reportDate +
                                                                   "\n" + Location;
                    xlSheet.HeaderFooter.OddFooter.LeftAlignedText = "&[Page] of &[Pages]";
                    xlSheet.HeaderFooter.OddFooter.RightAlignedText = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
```

After generating and opening the spreadsheet and navigating to the File\Print menu you will see that the footer is not quite right:

Here is a screen grab of the footer:
[Page of Pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ce5D9.png)

If I go to page setup and select custom footer the dialog box shows the footer information formatted correctly as &[Page] of &[Pages] and if I click on okay and let the dialog close the print preview then shows the footer correctly.

Here is a screen grab of the custom footer dialog box:
[Custom Footer Dialog Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPmhc.png)

I have tried using an explicit string and using &[Page] but they all return Page] of Pages] on the preview and exactly the text sent in the custom footer box.

I have exhausted my ideas for searching for help on this.

Can anyone help out?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the [ExcelHeaderFooter](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/blob/master/EPPlus/ExcelHeaderFooter.cs) object you will see a whole bunch of very helpful `const`'s to allow you accomplish what you want:

```
var wb = pck.Workbook;
var ws = wb.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
ws.Cells[1, 1].Value = "Test";

var footer = $"Page {ExcelHeaderFooter.PageNumber} of {ExcelHeaderFooter.NumberOfPages}";
ws.HeaderFooter.EvenFooter.CenteredText = footer;
ws.HeaderFooter.OddFooter.CenteredText = footer;
```

Here is what is listed as of version 4.1:

```
#region Static Properties
/// <summary>
/// The code for "current page #"
/// </summary>
public const string PageNumber = @"&P";
/// <summary>
/// The code for "total pages"
/// </summary>
public const string NumberOfPages = @"&N";
/// <summary>
/// The code for "text font color"
/// RGB Color is specified as RRGGBB
/// Theme Color is specified as TTSNN where TT is the theme color Id, S is either "+" or "-" of the tint/shade value, NN is the tint/shade value.
/// </summary>
public const string FontColor = @"&K";
/// <summary>
/// The code for "sheet tab name"
/// </summary>
public const string SheetName = @"&A";
/// <summary>
/// The code for "this workbook's file path"
/// </summary>
public const string FilePath = @"&Z";
/// <summary>
/// The code for "this workbook's file name"
/// </summary>
public const string FileName = @"&F";
/// <summary>
/// The code for "date"
/// </summary>
public const string CurrentDate = @"&D";
/// <summary>
/// The code for "time"
/// </summary>
public const string CurrentTime = @"&T";
/// <summary>
/// The code for "picture as background"
/// </summary>
public const string Image = @"&G";
/// <summary>
/// The code for "outline style"
/// </summary>
public const string OutlineStyle = @"&O";
/// <summary>
/// The code for "shadow style"
/// </summary>
public const string ShadowStyle = @"&H";
#endregion
```

Comment: Ernie, your advice was spot on and I have the sheet working correctly. Thanks also for the link to the documentation. I have no idea why I couldn't find it yesterday, guess I was too frustrated. Anyway, thanks.